# Bypassing immobiliser in a 1999 Subaru Forester

Tags: engine, electrical, starting, subaru

I have two paddock/farm vehicles. One is a 1998 Forester (black), auto, EJ20, no ignition immobiliser. The other is a 1999 Forester (green), manual, lo-range, immobiliser. Neither came with a FOB or an ignition key. My aim was to not spend a single cent on getting both running.
I dodgied up the black auto, and it runs beaut. Cut off the ignition lock, put in a few ignition switches and its fine.
I really want to get the Green manual, with low range, running. However, with the immobiliser it is difficult. Surely there is a method of bypassing the immobiliser?  Even if I have to open up the computer and solder in a wire from the security chip to another main chip(?)
I have swapped computers with no avail - I thought that the non-immobiliser computer from the running auto into the green manual, should have worked. 
With either computer, the manual turns over fine, spits out appropriate fuel, but of course, no spark from the coil pack. 
Found on a russian website where someone has the circuit of the immobiliser/sensor unit, but it is all drawn and handwritten in russian. Trying to decipher what it is is too hard!

Anyone have any experience?
Cheers. Dave.

Comment: What ecu do you have inside? I don't know off hand of a true immobilizer off solution but I know of some emulators that work on older Subaru's and may can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ask your local car thief.

Answer (score 1):

Mar 2022. I found my old post above. At the time of writing this there has been 1000 views! So, as an update for all future persons looking at this same issue, this is my story:

Sometime in 2020 I sent some 20 emails asking for help to 20 something Subaru so-called specialists all around Australia - everyone that I could find in google. Only one dude replied to my email. Now, I may not have mentioned it, but I did not have a FOB/Key at all. Ignition lock was smashed and I was trying to get it running completely bypassing all signals and codes that come from the original FOB. Coz I didnt have one. So, sometime a bit later I unsoldered the S220 EEPROM that is located within the alarm module, wired it up to a 9pin serial plug, plugged it into an old laptop with a serial port. used the eprom register modiyfing program called "PonyProg" , and it read the EEPROM beautifully. Docs can be found on the wiring diagram and PonyProg locations simply via google. I then null'ed out all of the registers containing the codes within the EEPROM. Soldered the EEPROM back into the module. Was going so well and thought that this was going to work, until smoke was let out.  "Bugger it!"
I then jumped on to a subie FB site and asked 'anyone have a computer-mounted-on-engine, FOB and ignition for sale for a 98/99 ?" $100 later a deal was done, plugged it all in, and away she went first turn of the ignition. I was blown away.
Chopped the back off it to turn it into a dual cab ute. Has been my good farm vehicle now for the past two years.

Comment: sounds like you soldered it back on backwards. This will reverse vcc and gnd and usually result in its death.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a programming button near the hood release lever.  You should be able to use this to disable the alarm system and get your forester started.

[image: Location of bypass button]

http://www.cars101.com/subaru/keyless.html#code%20alarm

Comment: Disabling the alarm does not disable the immobilizer. Two different things.

Comment: I had the same car/alarm system.  It wouldn't start if the alarm was not properly disarmed.  I had to do this several times when I didn't have the key fob handy.